# How to prove that $f(x,y) = \frac{2x^3+3y^3}{x^2y+xy^2}$ is a homogeneous function of degree $0$?

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Prove that the following function is a homogeneous function of degree $0$:

> $$f(x,y) = \frac{2x^3+3y^3}{x^2y+xy^2}$$

**My solution:**

> \begin{align}
>   f(tx, ty) &= \frac{2(xt)^3 + 3(yt)^3}{(xt)^2(yt)+(xt)(yt)^2} \\
>   &= \frac{t^3(2x^3+3y^3)}{t^3(x^2y+xy^2)} \\
>   &= t^0\times \frac{2x^3+3y^3}{x^2y+xy^2}
> \end{align}

Therefore, it is a homogeneous function of degree $0$. Is it sufficient enough to prove the statement?

Comment: Yes, this is enough to prove the statement.

Comment: You should consider providing your solution as an answer to your own question.